# Mutli-threaded giving results out of order

Tags: swift, multithreading

I'm really new to multithreading.  It has produced a result I wasn't expecting, but it makes sense when I think about it.  Now I need to find a way to make it work right.

Here is the scenario....

I have routine that calls a web page with a requested date.  Let's call it getPage(inDate: String).  The results are of unknown, but different sizes, depending on the date submitted.  (Today could have 100 items, tomorrow 2 items, the next day 10 items).

I have a loop that calls getPage, in date sequence.

Each return is a section in a tableview.

```
PSEUDO CODE 

func viewDidLoad() {   
    ...


    for cntr in 1...4 {
        getPage(calculatedDate)
    }

    ...
}

getPage(inDate: String) {
    let task = NSURLSession ( ....) {

    ...

    //  create tableview section data using self. arrays of string
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })


}
   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.dateSection.count // array of sections
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataItem1[section].count // an array of data for the section
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! calCell

    self.navigationItem.title = "Calendar Data"

    // Configure the cell...
    mycell.dataItem1.text =  self.data1[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    mycell.dataItem2.text = self.data2[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    mycell.dataItem3.text = self.data3[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    mycell.dataItem4.text = self.data4[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return mycell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    //        print("In titleForHederInSection:  Section \(section)")
    //        print("Title: \(self.dateSection[section])")
    return self.dateSection[section]
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter where I put the reload(), or if I use dispatch_sync or dispatch_async, the table is out of order...giving me the quickest returns first.

My initial attempts with semaphores has been a dismal failure...locking up the application forever.

So the question is, how do I get the viewtable to be built in the order that I called the web page (in this case, date order)?

Comment: You need to store an index with the request so you know where that data should go. Then place the results on the proper places based on that

Comment: Or, instead of `let task =`, you could store the references to the sessions you create in an array that matches the order of the sections you want their results to populate.